# Fluent Nhibernate HasMany on non primary key

Tags: nhibernate, fluent

```
**Table Order**
Id (PK)
NonUniqueId

**Table OrderLine**
Id (PK)
OrderNonUniqueId
Text
```

I have a legacy database where there OrderLine references Order via non primary key. A Order Line may belong to many Orders.

How can this be mapped at HasMany?

```
**OrderMap**
HasMany(x => x.OrderLines)
      .KeyColumn("OrderNonUniqueId")
```

(will not work since it uses the primary key Order.Id)

Answer (score 17):

Have you tried using `PropertyRef`?

```
public OrderMap()
{
  ...
  Map(x => x.NonUniqueId);
  HasMany<OrderLine>(x => x.Lines)
    .KeyColumn("OrderNonUniqueId")
    .PropertyRef("NonUniqueId");
  ...
}
```

It seems the extra `Map` is necessary otherwise fluent nhibernate complains. If you map the one-to-many within an hbm.xml file the extra property mapping for the `NonUniqueId` isn't required.